# CreateProcess error=2, Can not run program "python" on Ant

Tags: java, python, ant

I have a `C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Project\Workspace\testpython\verify_fam_extended.xml:52: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Project\Workspace\testpython\backend\generated"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` error when I run my xml code through Ant.

```
<exec dir="backend/generated" executable="python">
    <arg line="toplevel.py"/>
    <env key="PYTHONPATH" value="${dsltrans.install.path}:./backend/generated"/> 
</exec>
```

Comment: Check that your `%path%` environment variable contains the directory that `python.exe` resides in.

Comment: @cdarke my Path value is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\pl\bin;C:\Python22` and my python.exe is in C:\Python22

Comment: Formatted the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952935/java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-python-createprocess-error-2-the-sys/47953300#47953300 Only this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

**edit** `python.exe` must be in a directory defined in the executable path variable `PATH`.

Following working example assumes the presence of `C:\Python33\python.exe`

```
<project name="demo" default="main" basedir=".">
  <property environment="env" />
  <echo>PATH is set as: ${env.PATH}</echo>

  <target name="main">
    <exec dir="backend/generated" executable="python">
      <arg line="--version"/>
    </exec>        
  </target>                                
</project>
```

execute in a command session

```
set PATH=C:\Python33;%PATH%
ant
```

output

```
Buildfile: X:\temp\build.xml
     [echo] PATH is set as: C:\Python33;...
...
main:
     [exec] Python 3.3.0
```

**edit** Just checked. The executable can be `executable="python"` or `executable="python.exe"`. So @cdarke is right the issue is that `python.exe` is not in `PATH`.

Comment: I changed `python` to `python.exe` but still I have a problem.

Comment: The executable must be in the executable path. See the updated answer. I blindly assumed it would be the case already.

Comment: my Path value is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\pl\bin;C:\Python22 and my python.exe is in C:\Python22

Comment: Does it need to I change `${dsltrans.install.path}:./backend/generated` in the above code?

Comment: @any I add a working example. Seems in the session you execute `ant` the path to `python.exe` is not set as expected.

Comment: To clarify I use this code: https://github.com/levilucio/SyVOLT/blob/master/eclipse_integration/verify_fam_extended.xml
and I changed line 6 and 73.

Comment: if your means of path is user environmet value, this includes C:\ProgramFiles\Python22 this is the picture
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=4796488059&photo_id=21647968793

Comment: I don't understand `execute in a command session` part in your post.

Comment: @any Click on `Windows Start button` select `run...` type `cmd.exe` click `ok` go to your project directory (the one which contains the build.xml). I have not checked the github repository. How do you call `ant` to build the project?

Comment: @any I amend the `build.xml` to output the `PATH` setting when `ant` is running.