# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, eclipse, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I configured eclipse with pyspark

i am using latest version of SPARK and PYTHON.

when i try to code something and run. i get below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

code i have written is below

```
'''
Created on 23-Dec-2017

@author: lenovo
'''
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf

from builtins import int

#from org.spark.com.PySparkDemo import data

from pyspark.sql import Row

from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext



conf = SparkConf().setAppName("FileSystem").setMaster("local")

sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)

a = sc.textFile("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/file.txt")

b = a.map(lambda x:x.split(",")).map(lambda x:Row(id=int(x[0]),name=x[1],marks=int(x[2])))

c = sqlContext.createDataFrame(b)

c.show()
```

please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have installed pydev

under Windows > preferences > Pydev > interpreters > python interpreters > go to environment

under environment you need to give  path of `pyhton.exe` file, Variable name as `PYSPARK_PYTHON`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on Windows 10 with:

- Spark version 3.1.1
- Python version 3.9.4

Here's what I did:

- The directory "C:\spark\conf" had a file **spark-env.sh.template**. I changed it to **spark-env.cmd**.
- Kept all the existing text commented. (You'll have to replace # with :: for windows to comment)
- Added the following line to set PYSPARK_PYTHON variable.

  set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\python\python.exe

And it resolved the error. Referred this thread on stackoverflow : [encountered a ERROR that Can't run program on pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498049/encountered-a-error-that-cant-run-program-on-pyspark)

Comment: Where did you add the `set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\python\python.exe?`